# Python or Bash - How do you add words listed in a file in the middle of two sentences and put the output into another file?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I dont know how to define the variable 'set' and ' ' to then put a name and another ' ' before adding the last word 'username' and 'admin' in 'file2' for each name listed in 'file1'.

`file1 = [/home/smith/file1.txt]`

`file2 = [/home/smith/file2.txt]`

`file3 = file1 + file2`

Example:

[file1 - Names]

smith

jerry

summer

aaron

[file2 - Sentences]

set username

set admin

[file3 - Output]

set smith username

set smith admin

set jerry username

set jerry admin

set summer username

set summer admin

set aaron username

set aaron admin

Comment: python or bash? and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about your problem? And have you already tried something? If that is the case, please share it.

The way I see it you can open file2, read every line, split the two words on the space (and add it to a list for example). Then you can create a new string for every set of words you've created in that list. Loop on every line in file1. For every line in file1: take the first word from file2, add a space. Add the actual line from file1. And at last you add another space and the second word from.

You now have a new string which you can append to a new file for example. You should problably append that string to the new file in the same loop where you created the string.

But then again, I'm not shure if this is an answer to your question.

Comment: By the way, in my answer i assumed that the lines in the files are corresponding the each other.

Comment: This response should probably have been a comment on the question instead of an answer. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Jim. I'm kind of still figuring it out here. Makes it quite hard because I can't post comments to a question yet.

Comment: Jeff, that does make it more difficult doesn't it? :) OK. That's good feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in Bash, it answers your question

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=".../f1.txt"
file2=".../f2.txt"
file3=".../f3.txt"

while read p1; do
        while read p2; do
                word1=$(echo $p2 | cut -f1 -d' ')
                word2=$(echo $p2 | cut -f2 -d' ')
                echo " $word1 $p1 $word2" >> $file3
        done < $file2
done < $file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps..

```
names = file("/home/smith/file1.txt").readlines()
commands = file("/home/smith/file2.txt").readlines()
res = []
for name in names:
 for command in commands:
   command = command.split(" ")
   res.append(" ".join([command[0],name,command[1]]))
file("/home/smith/file3.txt","w").write("\n".join(res))
```

I'm sure this is not the prettiest way, but should work. But why do you want to do something like this...?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution using utilities only:

```
join -1 2 -2 3 file1 file2 | awk '{printf "%s %s %s\n", $2, $1, $3}' > file3
```